# Copy output from cat/less just like it's displayed

Tags: bash

What I want to do is to copy the output as you would do with a manual copy-paste. That mostly means that unrecognised characters will be saved as ? or however they are displayed, and not as their char codes. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `man cat` would tell you `cat -v` is a good option.

Comment: Doesn't work, it's like a plain `cat`.

Comment: What do you [really want to do](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something as manual copy&paste, so using a sort of clipboard, than that is operating system dependent and it is not a bash question.

For example, on MacOS X you can:

```
echo $filename | pbcopy      #pbcopy - save the output from echo to clipboard
find / -name 'pbpaste`       #pbpaste - print the clipboard content
```

Sure here is something like this on Linux too. (xclip or so)

as Erik told you, if you do

```
some_command > outfile ; cat outfile
```

it is the same as

```
some_command  #plain output to terminal.
```

in the file "outfile" you will get exactly the terminal output. (expect some rare cases)

and don't be confused with "less" or some other pagers, who really should change the unprintable characters to something else.

and lastly - if you have problems with codepage or so, try setup your environment variables like LANG, LC_ALL and LESSCHARSET (man less) and so on..

bash config

```
set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off
```

should help too in some cases. (man bash)

Try formulate you question more precise. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you had examples of what you are trying to solve, I could be more specific.

Right now, I can only point you at

- **less -SR** (show interpreting ANSI escapes)
- **[ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/zip/download.html#ansifilter)** to convert ANSI escaped text to plain text (or HTML etc)
- **[iconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)**, e.g.

.

```
cat myfile | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-1
```

Of course with that last one, substitute what ever character sets you have involved

### Update

I just worked out the two most likely settings that will do what I think you are describing:

```
cat position | iconv -t latin1//TRANSLIT
cat position | iconv -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
```

**If you have a UNICODE-heavy file `position` like this:**

```
 --> Applying move 131, ply 262: Q d3 - e2 + Checkmate .
... situation after:
⒏ ┊. . . . . . . . 
⒎ ┊. . ♟ . . . . . 
⒍ ┊. . ♙ . . . . . 
⒌ ┊. . ♙ . ♙ . . ♟ 
⒋ ┊. . . . ♘ ♜ . ♚ 
⒊ ┊. . . ▫ . . . . 
⒉ ┊. ♜ . . ♛ . . . 
⒈ ┊. . . . ♔ . ♗ . 
  └────────────────
   Ⓐ Ⓑ Ⓒ Ⓓ Ⓔ Ⓕ Ⓖ Ⓗ
```

**Will result in this:**

```
 --> Applying move 131, ply 262: Q d3 - e2 + Checkmate .
... situation after:
8. ?. . . . . . . . 
7. ?. . ? . . . . . 
6. ?. . ? . . . . . 
5. ?. . ? . ? . . ? 
4. ?. . . . ? ? . ? 
3. ?. . . ? . . . . 
2. ?. ? . . ? . . . 
1. ?. . . . ? . ? . 
  +----------------
   (A) (B) (C) (D) (E) (F) (G) (H)
```

Comment: Added complete sample with `iconv` and `//TRANSLIT`